# Which Enzymes are Responsible for the Biodegradation of Beta-endorphin?

Tags: biochemistry, enzymes, neurotransmitter

Which enzymes are responsible for the biodegradation of the endogenous opioid peptide, beta-endorphin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I have been able to find out, there isn't a definitive answer to this question.

β endorphin is a peptide, and it would seem that there are numerous brain peptidase enzymes that are implicated in the hydrolysis of β endorphin and other peptide neurotransmitters. These include aminopeptidase N, membrane-dipeptidase A, angiotensin-converting enzyme and neutral endopeptidase (also called enkephalinase).

For an early (1984) review of this topic see [here](http://igitur-archive.library.uu.nl/phar/2007-1214-203632/burbach_84_action%20of%20proteolytic%20enzymes%20on%20lipotropins.pdf); there doesn't seem to be a more up-to-date review, but there is quite a bit of literature on the effects of inhibitors of these various enzymes.